# How we can use git hub list view library

Tags: android, github, android-listview, android-listfragment

I want to make pull to refresh listview  for my application using this library:

https://github.com/erikwt/PullToRefresh-ListView

but I don't know how to import it in my android project. then say there is no project
 How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the zip bundle. Extract it into your workspace. The library is inside the libraryproject folder. You need to import that one. and if you are directly importing from github, again you need to navigate to the libraryproject and import it.